# Model of hive with Threads, multithread animation javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Assume that we have a hive where live bees. Every bee is an individual thread. Bee wants to go to hive and after some time go outside.

My question is how in JavaFX 8 animate move of bees without active waiting and sleeping of threads. What type of transformation should I use?

Comment: I tried to run translations separately, but I think it was a bad idea. What is the best solution to run all newly created translations?

Comment: I think this can all be done in one thread using AnimationTimer.

Comment: You need to define how an individual bee would move based on environment and/or time.

Comment: Can I add to Bee class list of transitions that are added independent and in AnimationTimer handle run transitions of all threads that have not empty list?

Comment: Probably not, but [transitions](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CJAJJAGI) makes since also.

Comment: So I don't have to run transitions in AnimationTimer handle method?

Comment: Animation timers are the way to do this.